# Помогите разобраться с типом

Tags: java

Пример из учебника такой :

```
import javax.sounds,midi.*;

public class MusicTest{

    public void play() {

        Sequenser sequenser = MidiSistem.getSequenser();
        System.out.println("Мы получили синтезатор")
    }
}
```

Вопрос почему в строчке : `Sequenser sequenser = MidiSistem.getSequenser();` тип переменной объявляется как `Sequenser`, а не `MidiSistem`.

По моему разумению строчка должна выглядеть так :

```
MidiSistem sequenser = MidiSistem.getSequenser();
```

Иначе получается какая-то непонятная для меня форма полиморфизма.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавлю некоторое обобщение к предыдущим ответам. Если у вас есть тип `T`, у которого есть (статический) метод `getX()`, то это совершенно не означает в общем случае, что этот метод вернет экземпляр типа `T` или даже `X`. Нужно смотреть на документацию/исходники.

Answer (score 5):

`MidiSistem.getSequenser();` является методом, который в результате возвращает объект класса `Sequenser`. По-моему все логично.

Comment: Прямо и добавить нечего

Comment: в точку! опередил на минуту)

Answer (score 0):

Когда вы берете методом `getSequenser();` из `MidiSistem` (*даже если дословно перевести - "получить Sequenser"*), то получаете объект `Sequenser` как раз.

На странице [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/midi/MidiSystem.html) всё поподробнее расписано.